# How to find out Spy and Leader in game?

Tags: probability

There is one game, the game organizer picks up 2*5 players, and splits them into two teams randomly, so each team has 5 players. Then, the battle of 5 players vs 5 players begin. There must be one team win the battle.

However, there is Spy and Leader in players. When spy and leader in the same battle, but in opposite team. Spy will loses the battle intentionally. On the other hand, when spy and leader in the same team, or in various battle, spy will try his best to win, just like normal players.

So, if we have enough battles and which team wins, how to find out Spy and Leaders?

In my opinion, this looks like a probability problem. Let

Event $A$: player1 defeat player2

Event $B$: player1, player2, player3 in one battle, and player1 in one team, (player2, player3) in the opposite team.

It looks like compare $P(A)$ and $P(A|B)$, if $P(A) > P(A|B)$, player3 may be one SPY, and player1 is player3's leader.

So, how to compute $P(A|B)$ ? Or, give me better idea about the problem.

tks~

Comment: Interesting question, though I do not think you've given us enough information to solve it.  In brief, I'd use [Maximum Likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation).  Look at the possible assignments of $S\&L$ and compute which of those would have had the highest probability of yielding the observed results.

Comment: Should have said:  this sounds like a simulation issue, not an analytic one.  Well, it depends on how relevant the other players are.  If you pick a pair, $A,B$ let's say and want to test the chance that $A$ is the leader and $B$ the Spy, you'll want to  sample the possible assignments of the other players.  Too many options to write out, but a simulation should get it done.  If the other players are irrelevant, it simplifies a lot...but presumably that is not true.

Comment: If the spy and leader are on the same team there is no way to find them as they behave just like normal players.